# generateTreeList() stopped working after running $this->Model->recover()

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.2.1

I have a model which I have set `var $actsAs = array('Tree');`

Previously I was able to run `$data = $this->JobType->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '-');` and `$data` would contain an entire view of the tree.

However, after running `$this->Area->recover($mode = 'parent', $missingParentAction = null);` I no longer get any results from `generateTreeList()` -- it is completely empty.

However, all of the other tree methods seem to be working perfectly well.

I have tried clearing all of the cake cache files to see if that made any difference but it didn't.

There is no error displayed even though I have debugging set to level 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I had UTF data in the array. Apparently Cake didn't like that. I still don't know why this happens, but to answer my own question, that is *why* it's happening.

If anyone wants to come and provide a more detailed answer then I'll happily mark it as correct instead!